# Spark complaining java.library.path missing in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

We have an AWS EMR cluster where we run some spark jobs. Jobs are submitted from an EC2 instance's docker container.
All the containers running spark job complaints below error. I have tried adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to spark-env and yarn-env, but the error still pops up. We cant read any CSVs due to this issue.

```
2022-03-31 11:57:48,605 ERROR lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Could not load native gpl library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(GPLNativeCodeLoader.java:32)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec.<clinit>(LzoCodec.java:71)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.$anonfun$getCompressionCodec$1(CodecStreams.scala:68)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.getCompressionCodec(CodecStreams.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CsvOutputWriter.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Can one of you help?

Comment: The error indicates your OS (or container) is missing some LZO libraries, which need to be installed separately from Spark

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it fully. are LZO libraries are missing in Ec2 docker?

Comment: Sure. For example, `apt install liblzo2-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working after adding:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/docker/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native

LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/librt.so.1

    new SparkConf().setExecutorEnv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
                   .setExecutorEnv("LD_PRELOAD", LD_PRELOAD)
```

Removing below property from core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
  </property>
```

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/577809?language=en_US